# Unable to install Ubuntu. (Invalid magic number)

Tags: system-installation, unetbootin

I have a windows 10 PC. Wanted to install Ubuntu.
I have tried installing ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 and xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64 both after downloading multiple times.

I used unetbootin to prepare the boottable USB drive.

It does not let me install or even run the live version. It gives me "Invalid magic number. Alloc Errort at x...."

I have seen similar issues in the forum but none answered properly.

Comment: Do you have access to a CD/DVD drive on your computer? If so, burn the .iso image to a DVD and then boot to the DVD. It'll be much more reliable for you. Keep us posted. Cheers, Al

Comment: Try using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Comment: I have the same issue booting the ISO image (from a virtual CD drive that works with every other Linux distro).  Something is wrong with Ubuntu/Kubuntu